# Do I have to use buttons?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I am making an app. It is kind of a hide and go seek. I was thinking about sectioning off separate areas and having the app say something different as to where you touched the screen. It will give you clues to where on the screen you need to touch next. So, these are my questions:
What is the easiest way? Would I want to make a grid of roundrectbuttons-placing each one and making an outlet for each - or can I make grid of buttons some other on the screen.If I place each button I will have a 9x12 of buttons making 108 buttons. Then I need to have a way to choose a random button as to where the location of the thing is question is. Would I use buttons at all or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3):

108 buttons is far too many to place in a xib :) If you wanted to use buttons then I would create them programatically in `viewDidLoad` in your controller.

Hoewever, I wouldn't use buttons at all!

I would use a [TapGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) attached to your background view. When you recieve a tap, take a look at where it was (use `locationInView:self.view`) and use that to work out what to do with the press.

Comment: It's really not "far too many." Through the magic of copy and paste, I created a grid of 96 buttons in half a minute or so. (The time consuming part will be setting the 'tag' for each of those buttons so you can tell them apart.) I'd probably go with creating them programmatically too -- just wanted to point out that iOS will *easily* handle that many objects in a view, and if each button needs to be customized anyway it might be very nice indeed to set them up in a .xib.

Comment: I wan't thinking about time, I was more thinking about efficiency - there is a way to solve this problem without creating _any_ buttons at all. Though you are right, if you wanted to use buttons then it work fine and if there was customisation needed then buttons would be the way to go. However if they are being used purely as a touch detection mechanism then I'd start looking at alternative methods :)